# Onclick on a radiobutton list using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, get

Hej,

I want to transfer the value of a radio button within a javascript to a new page using get. But nothing happens when I click on the radiobutton.

Unfortunately I don't know what to do and hope for your knowledge.

Thanks for your help!

Here is the script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#total_records').text(data.length);
    var html = '';
    if(data.length > 0)
    {
     for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
     {
      html += '<tr>';
      html += '<td> <input type="radio" name="auswahl" onclick="window.location.href = "kunden_bearbeiten.php?var=value" value="+data[count].id+"> </td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].id+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].firma+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].vorname+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].nachname+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].strasse+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].plz+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].ort+'</td></tr>';
     }
    }
    else
    {
     html = '<tr><td colspan="5">Kein Eintrag gefunden</td></tr>';
    }
    $('tbody').html(html);
   }
  })
 }

 $('#search').click(function(){
  var query = $('#tags').val();
  load_data(query);
 });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you listening to click event i mostly use onchange event. This will work for you.

```
<input type="radio" value="me" onchange="window.location='shop.php?value=' + this.value">
```

Comment: add also its onchange =' window.location.href = "kunden_bearbeiten.php?var="+ this.value' not var=value

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Unfortunately it has not yet solved my problem. I swapped the line for theirs and adjusted it, but that doesn't work either. If I now select the radiobutton and click on another one, both remain selected.

Comment: I added this:    html += '<td> <input type="radio" value="+data[count].id+" onchange="window.location="kunden_bearbeiten.php?value=" + this.value"> </td>';

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, that works for me. I changed the type from radio to submit.

```
<form method="get"><input class="ButtonSelect" type="submit" name="auswahl" formaction="kunden_bearbeiten.php?var=value" value="'+data[count].id+'"></form>
```